# Asp.net MVC5 client-side validation behavior different before and after a submit-element click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, client-side-validation

I have a dropdown with the "Select Country" default option, which I'd like to validate as invalid, if they choose "Select Country". The ajax and unobtrusive scripts are all in place. It actually works after the submit button is clicked, because of my [Required] attribute in the model class which deals with this particular page.

However, it does not work exactly how I'd like before the submit button is pressed: when I choose a valid option and tab away, it turns green as expected. But then I can select the default option again and it will *remain green*. In fact, some of the other text boxes also remained green when blank, but I wasn't actually able to reproduce this behavior unlike in the dropdown list.

And yet, after the form is submitted once and all the validation messages pop up, it works just as expected. Anyone else have such an experience.
I know this is easily solved with some javascript, but if there's something I'm fundamentally missing, I'd like to know.

This image is captured after:

1. input text into the City field
2. then tabbing out
3. then deleting all text from City field
4. selecting a valid item from Country drop down
5. tabbing out of Country drop down
6. selecting the default option in the Country drop down

[image]

However, after the submit element is clicked and unobtrusive validation reveals all the validation messages for all elements, the drop down take up expected behavior. Now when the default option is selected, the element is red. Why?

[image]

The POBox is not a required field, so green is Ok on that one.

Comment: If you have correct;y implemented client side validation, then the form wont even submit so you obviously have something wrong in your code

Comment: Yea I'm gonna have to check that- I was assuming that it wasn't actually submitting but haven't actually set the breakpoint in my controller to make sure. I meant "submit" as in the click on my submit button rather than the actual submission, but you're right I need to verify this.

Comment: I just checked and it works as expected- there is no actual submission, the unobtrusive javascript prevents submission.

Answer (score -1):

Hi If you have problem with client side validation, make sure that the following lines of codes available/correct in your project.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

OR if you are using bundling then make sure

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

And finally in the Webconfig file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Hope the above will be helpful like checklist.

Comment: The client scripts are all in place and the config file is as you describe, already. The issue appears to be in the scope of the unobtrusive validation only before the submission element is clicked for the first time, and only in the dropdown.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and although my original question was rather ambiguously worded regarding the term 'submit', I will have to respectfully downvote as it deals with a more basic issue of client validation working/not working whereas my issue is with it working properly in certain cases.